# Most effective way to run animation after set scroll amount

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fade in some elements on the page only when a certain part has been scrolled by

When the user scrolls past the header, some elements should load in.

Firstly I'm getting the header height:

```
var header_height = $('header').height();
```

And then I am running a test based on the `$window` element

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        // if scroll past 50
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= header_height) {
            console.log("scrolled " + header_height);
        } else {
            console.log("unscrolled " + header_height);
        }
    });
```

This works fine, but what happens is every pixel scrolls runs the script again. So although it works, I'm concerned it's not very efficient.

**Is there a better way to do this? E.g once user has scrolled `header_height`px, run this thing...**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u76v72qc/1/)

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: _The_ standard resource on performance of `scroll` event: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume, there exists a method in jQuery which triggers a function when the scroll height has exceeded header_height px. In such a case, jQuery would be doing the same thing, that is, checking if scroll position has reached header_height px or not.

So whether there is a method for this requirement or not, the performance of the code snippet should be same.

Comment: In addition, comparison operators are very quick. So the user would never see any performance hit due to it.

Comment: Thanks, I just wasn't sure as I guess I was concerned about the number of calculations happening.